# Akka stream - connect sink to source?

Tags: akka, akka-stream

I have the case when a `sink` (or an intermediate `flow`) can actually produce some side-effect data that has to be pushed back (or appended) to the `Source`. Is there a way to accomplish this using stream DSL? I could use some blocking queue or sort of it to create a `source` and then push data directly to that queue, however this is something that breaks the abstractions of streams. Perhaps there's a better solution I don't know about?

Comment: If the "sink" produces output, then it is not a sink but rather an effecting Flow.

Comment: @ViktorKlang okay, so can I connect a `Flow` to it's `Source` conditionally, so under certain circumstances the event emitted to by the this particular `Flow` will pass through the root of the Graph as it is emitted by a graph's `Source`?

Comment: Yes, it you use the GraphDSL and enable circular graphs. Keep in mind that circular, backpressured graphs requires a bit of deep thinking to get right.

Comment: I would rethink your design, it seems a bit odd that you would need the results of an intermediate flow to be pushed back to the original source.  I've seen many instances where a flow will generate some side effect data, e.g. db lookup, and forward on the input value as well as the side effect data (usually as a tuple).  But sending the results back to the original sink seems unnecessarily complex, and a HUGE PAIN to test/debug...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Viktor said, you can use circular graphs.

For example, the `partition` stage allows you to select particular elements of your stream.

```scala
  def partitionFunction(i: Int): Int = if (i % 2 == 0) 0 else 1

  val g = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder =>
    import GraphDSL.Implicits._
    val in = Source(1 to 10)
    val out = Sink.foreach[Int](println)

    val addOne = Flow[Int].map(_ + 1)

    val partition = builder.add(Partition[Int](2, partitionFunction))
    val merge = builder.add(Merge[Int](2))

                            in ~> merge ~> partition
    partition.out(0) ~> addOne ~> merge
    partition.out(1) ~> out

    ClosedShape
  })
```

In this example, the source `in` is connected to one input of the `merge`. The integers then pass through the `partition` stage which will separate even and odd.

The even are going through the `addOne` flow and then into the second input of the `merge` (which will get them back to the `partition` stage again).

The odd are directly going to the sink `out`.

This allows to feed some of the values back into the graph, but it can easily lead to a cycle (this is why the `addOne` stage is important here, without it the even numbers would have been trapped in the graph).

Answer (score 1):

[Reactive-kafka](https://github.com/akka/reactive-kafka) did something like that (in version 0.8 at least): it commits the messages consumed by Sink back to source (Kafka consumer).

[KafkaCommitterSink](https://github.com/akka/reactive-kafka/blob/0.8/core/src/main/scala/com/softwaremill/react/kafka/commit/KafkaCommitterSink.scala) is the implementation. It is not really a circular graph though, it rather 'updates' the source independently of a flow as far as I understand.